Count a table based on another table column
I have 2 tables, table F and table D. I want to count records from table F based on table D column called 'Oper'. I need to filter values between 160 and 165.
TABLE F



DEP
NUM
SERIAL




01
00001
1


01
00002
1


02
00001
1


02
00002
1


03
00001
1



TABLE D



DEP
#
NUM
SERIAL
Oper




01
1
00001
1
160


01
2
00001
1
160


01
3
00001
1
160


01
1
00002
1
161


01
2
00002
1
161


01
1
00003
1
160


02
1
00001
1
165


02
2
00001
1
165


02
1
00002
1
185


03
1
00001
1
163


03
2
00001
1
163


03
3
00001
1
163


03
1
00002
1
162



The results should be:



DEP
COUNT




01
3


02
1


03
2




Looks like you should be able to do that by using a JOIN to join both tables together and then do your count.

Here is a fiddle to help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/3TGUr6W9

Please have a go, and ask a question when stuck, showing us your attempt

@Brad I can't simply join the tables because it will repeat the values

You don't ask  anything here. Part of posting a question is asking a question. You've just posted some data and a vague requirement. Describe the problem. Demonstrate your attempts.  Explain why what you've tried didn't work or what about what you've read you didn't understand. Oh, and ask a question.

Removing "something like this" is hardly addressing @DaleK 's comment either...

@ThomA I had another comment (deleted now) saying that "something like this" isn't what we want - we need exactly what OP wants.

I joined the 2 tables on DEP, NUM, and SERIAL.
SELECT F.DEP,  COUNT(*) as COUNT
FROM TableF F
INNER JOIN TableD D on F.dep=d.Dep AND F.NUM=D.NUM and F.SERIAL=D.SERIAL
WHERE D.Oper between 160 AND 165
GROUP BY  F.DEP

fiddle
When I group by DEP I get the following counts



DEP
COUNT




1
5


2
2


3
3



